# Why the error: Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-innodb-cluster, mysql-group-replication

So i have this mysql innodb cluster of 3 mysql instances on docker that is always failing with the error group replication not active.

Looking at the error logs, the only thing i can find is this warning:

```
Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--relay-log=f3353ca0124a-relay-bin' to avoid this problem
```

I try the following query on the particular mysql instance 'f3353ca0124a'

```
show variables like '%relay_log%';
```

and i find

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value                                       |
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| max_relay_log_size        | 0                                           |
| relay_log                 | f3353ca0124a-relay-bin                      |
| relay_log_basename        | /var/lib/mysql/f3353ca0124a-relay-bin       |
| relay_log_index           | /var/lib/mysql/f3353ca0124a-relay-bin.index |
| relay_log_info_file       | relay-log.info                              |
| relay_log_info_repository | TABLE                                       |
| relay_log_purge           | ON                                          |
| relay_log_recovery        | OFF                                         |
| relay_log_space_limit     | 0                                           |
| sync_relay_log            | 10000                                       |
| sync_relay_log_info       | 10000                                       |
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.11 sec)
```

So i am confused cos it looks to me that the value which the error suggest i should set is already set.

Please can anyone help show me how to fix this error.